# sum of a series that looks almost like the Appell function

Tags: sequences-and-series, hypergeometric-function

Im trying to close the following series:

\begin{equation}
\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(a)_m(-a)_n}{(b)_m(b)_n}\frac{1}{m+n+c}\frac{1}{m!n!}(-z)^n z^m  
\end{equation}

i can write write

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{m+n+c}=\frac{\Gamma(m+n+c)}{m+n+c+1}=\frac{\Gamma(c)(c)_{m+n}}{\Gamma(c+1)(c+1)_{m+n}}=\frac{(c)_{m+n}}{c(c+1)_{m+n}}
\end{equation}

this then makes

\begin{equation}
\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(a)_m(-a)_n}{(b)_m(b)_n}\frac{(c)_{m+n}}{c(c+1)_{m+n}}\frac{1}{m!n!}(-z)^n z^m  
\end{equation}

now i tried too look at the appell function as listed in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html

is there some way i can write it in a form that is similar to the appell function?